# What's the best practice to pass Android access token to rails server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, oauth, facebook-android-sdk

I've read several articles about Facebook Login Security.

There were a few suggestions which inclue:

1. OAuth Code Flow.
2. App secret proof.

However, when I try to use Facebook Android SDK to retrieve OAuth code from a signed in request, it cannot be done.

How should I pass the Android access token to a server?

Comment: "cannot be done" is quite vague. please be a lot more specific and add what you have tried so far.

Comment: Use HTTPS, and pass it to the server. Make an API call from there to ensure the token is genuine.

Comment: Multiple gems exist for Oauth, and there is even a specific facebook Oauth gem : https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook.

Comment: @luschn, hmmm, to be more specific:


How do you perform OAuth Code Flow for Android-Rails?


How do you retrieve OAuth Code from Android App?

Comment: @Syl, yes, of course. I am aware of that.

Question is: How do you integrate Android SDK and the gem? Android SDK seems to work by itself.

Comment: @CBroe , is this the only approach? I thought Facebook suggested OAuth Code Flow authentication. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security

Comment: Of course you will be using OAuth, where else do you expect the access token to come from?

Comment: @CBroe, Facebook doesn't recommend passing access token over the air as that could be a security threats.

Comment: Where does it says so exactly?